# program to check is there any alphabet(a-z) exists in all string(list of novels) and print number of alphabets found

Tags: c++

will you please tell me what will be the procedure to find alphabet occur in all strings(char string lists) in c++
the output will only return matched values(alphabet numbers)
i m trying this

```
      #include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    //setup
    std::vector<int> alphabetCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        alphabetCount.push_back(0);
    }

    //now the interactive bit
    std::cout << "Enter a line of text\n";
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i)
    {
        char currentChar = tolower(line[i]);
        if (isalpha(currentChar))
        {
            ++alphabetCount[currentChar - 'a']; //subtract a, so if currentChar = a, 'a' - 'a' = 0, so its index 0
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < alphabetCount.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "there were " << alphabetCount[i] << " occurences of " << static_cast<char>(i + 'a') << "\n"; //add 'a' for the same reason as above, though we have to cast it to a char.
    }
system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

but it only returns values from single string i want result from all string

Comment: off topic: `std::vector<int> alphabetCount(26);` will pre-load the vector with 26 zeros and replace that first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is taking one string at a time is because you are taking one as input, you should make a vector of string and take input in it.

Comment: whould you please demonstrate?
i am new i can't understand

Answer (score 0):

You have not read the string more than once in program. below is sample program, which is very naive to demonstrate the process. The loop terminating condition can be much better than mine though.

```html
int main()
{
    //setup
    std::vector<int> alphabetCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        alphabetCount.push_back(0);
    }

    //now the interactive bit
    std::cout << "Enter a line of text\n";
    std::string line;
 do{
  std::getline(std::cin, line);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i)
  {
   char currentChar = tolower(line[i]);
   if (isalpha(currentChar))
   {
    ++alphabetCount[currentChar - 'a']; //subtract a, so if currentChar = a, 'a' - 'a' = 0, so its index 0
   }
  }
 }while(line != "exit");

 --alphabetCount['e' - 'a'];
 --alphabetCount['x' - 'a'];
 --alphabetCount['i' - 'a'];
 --alphabetCount['t' - 'a'];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < alphabetCount.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "there were " << alphabetCount[i] << " occurences of " << static_cast<char>(i + 'a') << "\n"; //add 'a' for the same reason as above, though we have to cast it to a char.
    }
 system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: recommend using empty string rather than "exit " for the terminator. Easier to type and no clean-up.